# Show active ip-addresses in linux script with % or UP/DOWN

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have an ip-address: 192.168.0.205
I can ping it in a script:

```
for i in 192.168.0.205 ....
do
  ping -c 1 $i
done
```

but now I want the script shows:
192.168.0.205 UP or DOWN

Is there also a way to show it in % e.g: 75% UP?

Comment: Why not increase the number of pings with `-c 100` and then you get the percentage of packet loss for free.

Comment: Do you want to know the %age of active IP addresses in a network or the packet loss ratio in pinging a single IP?

Comment: I want to know the active IP addresses e.g 3 ping good, 1 fail so I want 75% UP

Comment: But the most important is that he says ... up or down.

Answer (score 0):

What you may want is this:

```
x=0;
a=1
b=5
for((i=$a;i<=$b;i++))
do
    y=`ping -n 1 192.168.1.$i | grep unreachable | wc -l`
    x=$(($x + $y))
done;
echo "$x $b $a" | awk '{printf "%.2f %% DOWN\n",($1/($2-$3+1))*100}';
```

x: contains the number of DOWN IPs

a: last octet of first IP address

b: last octet of last IP address

y: contains 0 if an IP is UP else 1

I hope that helps!

PS: Change -n to -c or whatever option does the work in your shell!

Comment: I did it like you wrote it but I have a syntax error from 1 192... 'til -l"

Comment: did you try changing -n to -c?

Comment: yes I changed -n to -c but the problem starts from greb I guess. Can I change unreachable in packet loss?

Comment: "unreachable" is just a word that appears when we cannot ping an IP. You can surely change it to your requirement.

Comment: It doesn't works. Always error. Do you know how I can just show up or down after my ip-address?